# Less verbose member variables on ChangeNotifer class?

Tags: flutter, state-management

I was learning Svelte on my free time and got jealous of their [simple reactive values](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations).

Is there any way to define a simple value that when changed automatically calls notifyListeners? For example, I have a `_isDarkMode` setting inside a Settings class that needs 6 loc just to accommodate the `notifyListeners`  call.

```dart
class Settings with ChangeNotifier {
  /* ... */
  bool _isDarkMode;
  bool get isDarkMode => _isDarkMode;
  set isDarkMode(bool isDarkMode) {
    _isDarkMode = isDarkMode;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Is it possible for a mixin to override a member's automatic setter creation to include `notifyListeners()` so the only thing I'd need to do is create the value and update it to have the ui react:

```dart
class Settings with ChangeNotifier, Mixin {
  bool isDarkMode;
}
```

where the mixin might look like

```dart
mixin Mixin on ChangeNotifier {
  // Not at all correct
  @override
  set value(newValue) {
    set(newValue); // <- Call dart's automatic setter creation ??
    super.notifyListners();
  }
}
```

Sorry if I'm thnking about this the wrong way! Still relatively new to all things Dart

Answer (score 1):

It's a great idea and it would be nice to have this is an option but i don't think that's possible, at least not with the use of mixins.

Mixins can't hold to much semantic of the class, it can't know how to create these setters because mixin is agnostic of the class because you can plug a mixin anywhere.

Although this could be nice, it will bring some problems. Along with that you will have to figured out a way to cancel notify when you don't want the ui to react (that's always that case).